# Change the class of selected <li> in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to change the class of selected li element in my lwc component
HTML:

```
<template for:each={itemsListNew} for:item="myitem">
                                    <li data-value={myitem.pItem.value} onclick={handleSelect} key={myitem.pItem.value}  class={myitem.classList} role="presentation" >
                                        <a data-value={myitem.pItem.value} onclick={handleSelect} aria-selected="true" class="slds-path__link" href="javascript:void(0);" id={myitem.pItem.value} role="option"
                                            tabindex="0">
                                            <span class="slds-path__stage">
                                                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:check" alternative-text="Warning!" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Current Stage:</span>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="slds-path__title">{myitem.pItem.label}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </template>
```

And on click method :

```
handleSelect(event) {
    this.selectedValue = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;


    event.target.classList.add("slds-path__item slds-is-current slds-is-active"); 
          
}
```

I'm trying to update the class of selected li, how can I do that ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple classes use comma separated string values

```js
event.target.classList.add('slds-path__item','slds-is-current','slds-is-active');
```